# How to filter out records grouped by date with a large date difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some records, grouped by name and date.

I would like to find any records in a table that have a date difference between them larger than a week, from the most recent record.

Would this be possible to do with a cte?

I am thinking something along these lines (it is difficult to explain)

```
; with mycte as ( 
  select *
    from @GroupedRecords)
select *
  from mycte a
  join (select *
          from @GroupedRecords) b on a.Name = b.Name
 where datediff(day, a.DateCreated, b.DateCreated) > 7
```

For example:

```
Id  Name    Date
1   Foo     02/03/2010
2   Bar     23/02/2010
3   Ram     21/01/2010
4   Foo     29/02/2010
5   Foo     22/02/2010
6   Foo     05/12/2009
```

The results should be:

```
Id  Name    Date
1   Foo     02/03/2010
5   Foo     22/02/2010
6   Foo     05/12/2009
```

Comment: Show your query. `HAVING` might be an option.

Comment: please elaborate your question more ?

Comment: If you could show sample data from your table and the result you're expecting to get that would make things MUCH easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       DATE
FROM   groupedrecords AS gr1
WHERE  ( (SELECT MAX(DATE) AS md
          FROM   groupedrecords gr2
          WHERE  gr1.name = gr2.name) - gr1.DATE ) > 7;
```

Or probably better yet:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       DATE
FROM   groupedrecords AS gr1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT name,
                          MAX(DATE) AS md
                   FROM   groupedrecords AS gr2
                   GROUP  BY name) AS q1
         ON gr1.name = q1.name
WHERE  ( q1.md - gr1.DATE ) > 7;
```

UPDATE: As suggested in the comments, here is a version that uses union to get the id with the max date per group AND the ids of those that are 7 days or older than the max date. I used a CTE for fun, it was not necessary. Note that if there is more than 1 ID that shares the max date in a group, this query will need to be modified-

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT name,
                Max(date) AS MD
         FROM   Records
         GROUP  BY name)

SELECT R.ID,
       R.name,
       R.date
FROM   CTE
       INNER JOIN Records AS R
         ON CTE.Name = R.Name
            AND CTE.MD = R.date
UNION ALL
SELECT r1.id,
       r1.name,
       r1.DATE
FROM   Records AS R1
       INNER JOIN CTE
         ON CTE.name = R1.name
WHERE  ( CTE.md - R1.DATE ) > 7
ORDER  BY name ASC,
          date DESC
```

Comment: the problem I see with this query is it misses the recent most record (#1 in the example), May be UNION the two result sets?

Comment: Good catch...it's unstated whether they actually wanted the most recent record included...I will edit my answer if the OP wants the most recent date also.

Comment: it is understood from the expected output in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this gets close to a solution:

```
; with tableWithRow as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by name, date) as rowNum
  from t
)
select t1.*, t2.id t2id, t2.name t2name, t2.date t2date, t2.rowNum t2rowNum
from tableWithRow t1
join tableWithRow t2
on t1.rowNum = t2.rowNum + 1 and t1.name = t2.name
```